# repeatability rate in OpenCV

Tags: c++, opencv, feature-detection

I use the following code to detect describe and evaluate features in OpenCV 2.4.10 with C++ in Microsoft Visual Studio 2012.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
#include <opencv2/core/core.hpp>
#include <opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp>
#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>
#include <opencv2/nonfree/features2d.hpp>
#include <opencv2/legacy/legacy.hpp>

using namespace cv;
using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char ** argv)
{
  Mat image1;
  image1 = imread(argv[1], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE); // Read the first file

  Mat image2;
  image2 = imread(argv[2], CV_LOAD_IMAGE_GRAYSCALE);

  if ((!image1.data) || (!image2.data)) {
    std::cout << "ERROR: Cannot load images in\n" << argv[1] << "\n" << argv[2] << endl;
    return -1;
  }

  vector < KeyPoint > keypoints1, keypoints2;
  cv::Mat descriptors1, descriptors2;

  /** Construction of the feature detector
   */

  double ExTime = (double) cv::getTickCount();
  cv::SurfFeatureDetector surf(800);

  /** Detection of the features
   */
  surf.detect(image1, keypoints1);
  surf.detect(image2, keypoints2);

  cv::SurfDescriptorExtractor surfDesc;
  surfDesc.compute(image1, keypoints1, descriptors1);
  surfDesc.compute(image2, keypoints2, descriptors2);

  //Calculate the time needed for code execution
  ExTime = ((double) cv::getTickCount() - ExTime) / cv::getTickFrequency();

  /** Draw the keypoints
   */
  Mat ImageKP1, ImageKP2;

  drawKeypoints(image1, keypoints1, ImageKP1, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);
  drawKeypoints(image2, keypoints2, ImageKP2, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

  // Construction of the matcher 
  cv::Mat ImageMatch;
  cv::FlannBasedMatcher matcher;

  // Match the two image descriptors    
  std::vector < DMatch > matches;
  matcher.match(descriptors1, descriptors2, matches);

  double max_dist = 0;
  double min_dist = 100;

  //-- Quick calculation of max and min distances between keypoints
  for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++) {
    double dist = matches[i].distance;
    if (dist < min_dist) min_dist = dist;
    if (dist > max_dist) max_dist = dist;
  }

  //-- Draw only "good" matches (i.e. whose distance is less than 2*min_dist,
  //-- or a small arbitary value ( 0.02 ) in the event that min_dist is very
  //-- small)
  std::vector < DMatch > good_matches;

  for (int i = 0; i < descriptors1.rows; i++) {
    if (matches[i].distance <= 2 * min_dist) {
      good_matches.push_back(matches[i]);
    }
  }

  cout << "Number of good matches: " << good_matches.size() << endl;

  drawMatches(image1, keypoints1, image2, keypoints2, good_matches, ImageMatch, cv::Scalar(255, 0, 255), cv::DrawMatchesFlags::DRAW_RICH_KEYPOINTS);

  /** Evaluation of detected points
   */
  std::cout << ">" << std::endl;
  cout << "Evaluating feature detector..." << endl;
  float repeatability;
  int corrCounter;
  cv::Mat Homog;

  std::vector < cv::Point2f > srcKey;
  std::vector < cv::Point2f > refKey;

  for (int i = 0; i < matches.size(); i++) {
    srcKey.push_back(keypoints1[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
    refKey.push_back(keypoints2[matches[i].queryIdx].pt);
  }

  Homog = cv::findHomography(srcKey, refKey, CV_RANSAC, 1);

  cv::evaluateFeatureDetector(image1, image2, Homog, & keypoints1, & keypoints2, repeatability, corrCounter);

  std::cout << "repeatability = " << repeatability << std::endl;
  std::cout << "correspCount = " << corrCounter << std::endl;
  std::cout << ">" << std::endl;

  system("pause");

  return 0;
}
```

The problem is that `repeatability` rate is always -1, as well as the `correspCount`.
I use my images, which have a large overlap and many features are detected. I couldn't find a tutorial in the official site of OpenCV about the function

```
cv::EvaluateFeatureDetector
```

but just some tutorial in sites like this one. There are some similar questions, but no one with always -1 as a return. What may be wrong?

Comment: Did u check your homograph matrix? Is it giving reasonable result?

Answer (score 0):

If you check [the source code](https://github.com/opencv/opencv/blob/master/modules/features2d/src/evaluation.cpp) for `evaluateFeatureDetector` function, it checks the keypoints and calls the `calculateRepeatability` function. In that function, at line 436:

```
correspondencesCount = -1;
repeatability = -1.f;
if( overlaps.empty() )
    return;
```

The values are set to -1 and if there are no overlaps between the filtered keypoints in two images, then those values are returned. In this case, since your actual keypoint vectors are not empty, I would say your homography is incorrect. That may result from having images that are not similar enough, or the homography is calculated incorrectly. Since you assure that the first one is not the case, I would suggest you to suspect the resulting homography matrix. You can use [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/doc/tutorials/features2d/feature_homography/feature_homography.html) to draw the image under perspective transformation by the resulting homography, so that if the image is distorted unexpectedly you will have a clue about how/why the above function is failing.